# Does Rhino let me mock a generic method based on type?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

It's easy to mock a method like `string DoStuff(int input)` for different values of `input`, with a default for all non-listed values.

But what about a method like `string DoStuff<T>()` for different types `T`?

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set a behavior for generics methods like `string DoStuff<T>()`:

```
public class IFoo
{
    public string DoSomthing<T>();
    public string DoSomthing<T>(T t);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{

    var fakeObj = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();

    fakeObj.Stub(x => x.DoStuff<int>()).Return("1");
    fakeObj.Stub(x => x.DoStuff<long>()).Return("10");
    fakeObj.Stub(x => x.DoStuff<string>()).Return("XD");
    fakeObj.Stub(x => x.DoStuff(3)).Return("2");


    Assert.AreEqual("1", fakeObj.DoStuff<int>());
    Assert.AreEqual("XD", fakeObj.DoStuff<string>());
    Assert.AreEqual("10", fakeObj.DoStuff<long>());
    Assert.AreEqual("2", fakeObj.DoStuff(3));

}
```